# Pandas - Filter DF to contain only rows in which each column is FALSE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains only boolean values. I would like to split this into two dataframes; the first containing rows in which every column's value is False, and the second containing rows in which 1 or more column's value is True.

I know this is a very solvable problem in pandas just having trouble putting together the solution

Thank you

Comment: Day 100: Still cannot find your data or your code... where is it?! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[-df.any(axis=1)] # All Falses; not any one is True
df[ df.any(axis=1)] # Not all Falses
```

Comment: had some formatting trouble above, what I want to say: Thank you for your answer. To make this problem a little more difficult.. what if I wanted to include a single column (unique identifier) that was not a boolean but rather a string, and I wanted to maintain that column throughout the filtering process @DyZ